# Covert array to json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array like this

```
[ 'quality',
  'print-quality: 4',
  'x-dimension',
  'Value: 21590',
  'Value: y-dimension',
  'Value: 27940',
  'Value: ',
  'Value: media-bottom-margin',
  'Value: 0',
  'Value: media-left-margin',
  'Value: 0',
  'Value: media-right-margin',
  'Value: 0',
  'Value: media-top-margin',
  'Value: 0',
  'Value: ' ]
```

am trying to convert this array to a `json` in the following format

```
 { "quality": "print-quality: 4",
  "x-dimension": "21590",
  "y-dimension": "27940", 
  "media-bottom-margin": "0",
  "media-left-margin" : "0",
 "media-right-margin": "0",
  "media-top-margin" : "0" 
 }
```

I need to remove all 'Value' string also how it can be obtain in the above format

Comment: Are you simply ignoring the 'Value: ' elemets?

Comment: not ingoring the full value..i need the integer part like '0' no need the string 'Value :'

Comment: So what is the problem with just doing that?

Comment: @SantiagoHernández also quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create an associative array like that because JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays. But you can create an object, which is really what you want here.

Here's one way to do it:

```
var data = [ 'quality',
        'print-quality: 4',
        'x-dimension',
        'Value: 21590',
        'Value: y-dimension',
        'Value: 27940',
        'Value: ',
        'Value: media-bottom-margin',
        'Value: 0',
        'Value: media-left-margin',
        'Value: 0',
        'Value: media-right-margin',
        'Value: 0',
        'Value: media-top-margin',
        'Value: 0',
        'Value: ' ],
    cleanData,
    newData = {}; // initialize the new object

cleanData = data
    .map( function(x) { return x.replace(/^Value: /, ''); }) // remove leading "Value: " 
    .filter( function (x) { return !x.match(/^$/); } ); // strip empty values 

for (i = 0; i < cleanData.length; i += 2) { // loop over the cleaned-up array
    newData[cleanData[i]] = cleanData[i + 1];
}
```

The result is that `newData` (in JSON form for readability) is:

```
{
    "quality":"print-quality: 4",
    "x-dimension":"21590",
    "y-dimension":"27940",
    "media-bottom-margin":"0",
    "media-left-margin":"0",
    "media-right-margin":"0",
    "media-top-margin":"0"
}
```

Comment: pretty creative with that, i like it, who knows who downvote but here is +1 sir

Comment: @Santiago Hernández: "pretty creative" --- how would you do it the other way? It's a naive implementation.

Comment: well as Ed Cottrell said "Here's one way to do it" there are a lot of ways to do it with native javascript code, if you ask me for another way i'd use [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with regex ;), have fun @zerkms

Comment: @SantiagoHernández and it's basically the same - you just use `forEach` instead of `for`

Comment: @zerkms all right, so here you are: `var json = {};
data.toString().replace(/Value: /gi,"").replace(",,",",").replace(/,$/,"").split(",").forEach(function(el,i,a){if(i%2==0) json[el] = a[i + 1];});` that will do the trick. i'm not using `map` nor `filter` :) good night